# Edit existing polygons to include several new nodes

Tags: qgis, polygon, vertices, catchment-area

I want to define catchments which are quite large from vector contour data.  I normally start zoomed out to define the catchment generally as it is easier to see.  I then zoom in and refine the catchment.

Currently I add a new node then move it into position to refine the catchment.  However is there a way to add additional "runs" of new nodes between two existing nodes to expedite the process.

I am using QGIS, with my contour data being vector data comprising poly lines with an elevation attribute defining its level.

Comment: If you want to add additional nodes between two existing nodes you can use "Node tool" just need to double click where you would like to additional nodes.

Comment: Thanks pugazh, that is what I want to do now, but I find if I want to add quite a few points it becomes tedious.  I was hoping that there was an option to skip a few of the clicks.

Comment: Are you trying to [Reshape](http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/create_vector_data/topo_editing.html#moderate-fa-tool-reshape-features) the features?

Comment: @Pugazh you must write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of in QGIS is the menu: `Vector > Geometry Tools > Densify Geometries`.

It will add a given number of nodes between any existing nodes. In the image below I add two nodes (=vertices) extra between any existing nodes.

[image]

[image]